# size of heap memory required to process records

Tags: eclipse, heap-memory

I am processing a data having 1 million records in eclipse.I have increased my heap memory from -xmas 256m to -xmas 512m and -xmax 1024m to -xmax 2048m.still the outofmemory error is coming as follow:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java 
heap space
at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(Unknown Source)
at java.io.StringWriter.write(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:1129)
at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:1104)
at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:1050)
at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(IOUtils.java:359)
at WorkSpot.Ftp.getmfebcdata(Ftp.java:372)
at WorkSpot.ParseData.parsetolines(ParseData.java:112)
at WorkSpot.SheetFormat.getsheet(SheetFormat.java:55)
at WorkSpot.MainScreen$1.actionPerformed(MainScreen.java:492)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown 
Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
```

Please help me in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong switches, you need `-Xms` and `-Xmx`. For example, `-Xmx1024m`, please note the absence of spaces as well. See [this link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/web.1111/e13814/jvm_tuning.htm#i1124418) for more information on the switches.

Answer (score 1):

The eclipse.ini settings change the memory used by Eclipse itself, they do **not** change the memory settings of programs you run from inside Eclipse. It is rare to need to change this file.

To change the settings for your program open the 'Run > Run Configurations' dialog.

Find your program configuration in the Java Applications section.

On the 'Arguments' tab put the -Xms and -Xmx settings in the 'VM Arguments' section.